# Cant connect UITableViewCell custom cell IBOutlet

Tags: uitableview, interface-builder, iboutlet

Im trying to connect UITableViewCell IBOutlet. I have made a UITableView cell in the interface builder,

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
     {    
         IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
         IBOutlet UITableViewCell *customCell;
     }
```

When trying connect the new referencing outlet into the files owner, nothing showing to connect(No items displayed for connect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you have done ? But your problem seems to be with the xib file's file ownership. May be you have created xib separately & forgot to set the ownership to the header you are trying to get suggestion from. **If this is the problem, you can check it out by going to identity inspector in right nib helper pane (third from left) and check what is it's Custom Class.** If it's not ViewController then there lies your problem. Set it to ViewController (Your class name for file's owner), clean & build. I hope that helps.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the tableview cell class?